# Is there any way to convert html file to IN-MEMORY File as PDF in Java?

Tags: java, html, spring, maven, pdf-generation

I have been given an HTML file and wanted to convert it into an **in-memory** PDF file. During the conversion, I don't want to use any external location for this. All I want is to keep it **in-memory**.

So far, I have already tried some **Java** libraries for the conversion but all of them always create a temporary file in a location and then read/write from it. I don't want any I/O operation during the conversion.

Comment: Consider looking for other Java libraries (or more closely at the once you already have tried), most libraries allow the use of `InputStream` and `OutputStream` instead of files for reading and writing files. Here you can work with `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` objects. I assume this is what @life888888 wanted to express in their answer.

Comment: @KJ That doesn't make sense. There is no need for a PDF to hit a filesystem. The libraries used by OP merely work that way and OP is asking for a library that doesn't. I think SO guidelines indicate that means it's vote-to-close: Asking for library suggestions, but I'm not sure and the question sure feels specific enough to be worth asking here.

Comment: @MohammadSohail this question would be much improved if you explain which library(ies) you tried and the code you used to do it - it is possible that one of these libraries _does_ let you do this in-mem, but you simply didn't call the right methods.

Comment: @KJ That's just plain incorrect. a PNG is just as much as file format as PDF is (it's a "raster graphics file format"), and yet I can generate a PNG in memory, and ship it in memory over TCP/IP to a browser, and the browser will then render it to the user, with the file system never being involved. OP no doubt wants to make a PDF from HTML and ship it over e.g. TCP/IP and correctly sees no need to involve a disk intermediary. It is of course possible to generate it all in memory, without using a virtual filesystem driver. I do this all the time (but not in java, so I have no direct answer).

Answer (score 1):

The HTMLWorker class was deprecated many years ago. The goal of HTMLWorker was to convert small, simple HTML snippets to iText objects. It was never meant to convert complete HTML pages to PDF, yet that was how many developers tried to use it. This caused plenty of frustration because HTMLWorker didn't support every HTML tag, didn't parse CSS files, and so on. To avoid this frustration, HTMLWorker was removed from recent versions of iText.

In 2011, iText Group released XML Worker as a generic XML to PDF tool, built on top of iText 5. A default implementation converted XHTML (data) and CSS (styles) to PDF, mapping HTML tags such as
`<p>`
,
`<img>`
, and
`<li>`
to iText 5 objects such as Paragraph, Image, and ListItem. We don't know of any implementations that used XML Worker for any other XML formats, but many developers used XML Worker in combination with jsoup as an HTML2PDF converter.

XML Worker wasn't a URL2PDF tool though. XML Worker expected predictable HTML created for the sole purpose of converting that HTML to PDF. A common use case was the creation of invoices. Rather than programming the design of an invoice in Java or C#, developers chose to create a simple HTML template defining the structure of the document, and some CSS defining the styles. They then populated the HTML with data, and used XML Worker to create the invoices as PDF documents, throwing away the original HTML. We'll take a closer look at this use case in chapter 4, converting XML to HTML in memory using XSLT, then converting that HTML to PDF using the pdfHTML add-on.

When iText 5 was originally created, it was designed as a tool to produce PDF as fast as possible, flushing pages to the OutputStream as soon as they were finished. Several design choices that made perfect sense when iText was first released in the year 2000, were still present in iText 5 sixteen years later. Unfortunately, some of these choices made it very difficult –if not impossible– to extend the functionality of XML Worker to the level of quality many developers expected. If we really wanted to create a great HTML to PDF converter, we would have to rewrite iText from scratch. Which we did.

In 2016, we released iText 7, a brand new version of iText that was no longer compatible with previous versions, but that was created with pdfHTML in mind. A lot of work was spent on the new Renderer framework. When a document is created with iText 7, a tree of renderers and their child-renderers is built. The layout is created by traversing that tree, an approach that is much better suited when dealing with HTML to PDF conversion. The iText objects were completely redesigned to better match HTML tags and to allow setting styles "the CSS way."

For instance: in iText 5, you had a PdfPTable and a PdfPCell object to create a table and its cells. If you wanted every cell to contain text in a font different from the default font, you needed to set that font for the content of every separate cell. In iText 7, you have a Table and Cell object, and when you set a different font for the complete table, this font is inherited as the default font for every cell. That was a major step forward in terms of architectural design, especially if the goal is to convert HTML to PDF.

But let's not dwell on the past, let's see what pdfHTML can do for us. In the first chapter, we'll take a look at different variations of the convertToPdf()/ConvertToPdf() method, and we'll discover how the converter is configured.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for generating HTML to pdf that works for me:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();

    MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();

    ByteArrayDataSource bds = new ByteArrayDataSource(outputStream.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
    att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds));
    att.setFileName("example.pdf");
}
```

Comment: You may want to add the PDF libraries required here.

Comment: @mkl it is flying-saucer-pdf